# How to create a Trigger batch file after Checking for the existence of 2 files in a partculare shared folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have `file1` and `file2` arriving in some shared folder. They are triggered files created after a database refresh. I need one new file to be created in the same shared folder after `file1` and `file2` arrive in that location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you provide some more information, such as what OS and database you are using?  And can you share any code you've already attempted so that we know what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple. the `ping` command is a way to get a delay (5s, in this case) on Windows.

```
:CHECK_LOOP
IF EXIST file1 (
    IF EXIST file2 (
        echo.>file3
    )
)
ping -n 5 localhost >NUL 2>NUL
GOTO :CHECK_LOOP
```

Comment: thanks a million Jubjub. this seems to be working. i will get back to you if i need any further help on this. God day!